# SVG change text via attribute

Tags: svg

I want to manually create an svg of a directory tree, and thought it would be nice to do it in a way that makes it easy to add, move or delete elements from that tree (without having to repeat myself too much).

While skimming through the svg specification i noticed the `<use>` element, which allows to "include" other elements with the option to override some of the attributes. So what i would like to do is define the symbol for a folder (or file), including the corresponding label, and then set the actual text of the label via `<use>`.

Essentially something like this (which doesn't work of course):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="folder">
            <g width="24" height="24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path d="M22 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h5l2 3h9a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z" />
            </g>
            <text x="28" y="12" dominant-baseline="middle">my_text</text>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <use href="#folder" my_text="root"/>
        <g transform="translate(24)">
            <use y="24" href="#folder" my_text="foo"/>
            <g transform="translate(24)">
                <use y="48" href="#folder" my_text="bar"/>
            </g>
            <use y="72" href="#folder" my_text="hello"/>
            <use y="96" href="#folder" my_text="world"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

So, is there any way to use the value of an attribute as the actual text of a `<text>` element?

PS: Please note that this svg file is not supposed to be part of a web page, but should be rendered correctly when i open it in another application (like inkscape, or any other svg editor/viewer) or generate a pdf from an Asciidoc document.